# Quality Gate periods (SonarQube 5.4)

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1, sonarqube-5.4

We want to upgrade our SonarQube Server from the 5.0 version to the current 5.4. 
We imported our Quality Profiles, and had to set the Quality Gates manually (we found no way to do that automatically).

Now I have the problem, that i cant use the Value Δ since previous analysis , only "Value" and "Leak". We have to use this property, because our company have large projects with legacy Code.

[image]

Does anyone know, what happened with this Property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since SonarQube 5.4 the only Differential Period available for Quality Gate conditions is the Leak Period (see [5.4 Upgrade Notes](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Release+5.4+Upgrade+Notes)).

The Leak Period can be customized at a project level (see [Differential Views Settings](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Differential+Views#DifferentialViews-DifferentialViewsSettings)). It currently defaults to `since_previous_version` but you are free to set it to `previous_analysis` (amongst other options) if you wish.