# Sonarqube 5.4 Leak Configuration issue

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-5.4

I've got an issue with my Quality Gate defines. For a single gate I have multiple rules for checking against other results. There are for example some rules comparing new issues of several certainities to the last analysis and some rules against the last project version.

In Differential View setup I can define multiple periods, e.g. last analysis or last version. When defining the rules I can only select Leak as type.

How may I define which of the rules are compared to the last analysis (Leak Period 1) and which against the last project version (Leak Period 2)?

Thanks for your help.

Christian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot mix various differential periods in a Quality Gate since SonarQube 5.4. As per [upgrade notes](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Release+5.4+Upgrade+Notes):

> In SonarQube 5.4, quality gate conditions can now only check absolute values or differential values for the Leak period

So while you may still customise the `Leak Period` at a project level (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36720330/)), all Quality Gate conditions will either use that same period or the absolute value.

Comment: Thanks. That's a pity. So I will have to have a talk about the change of Quality Gate status.

But whats the benefit of the several periods you may define under differential views if you can only check against one?